# How to remove administrator's own comments on the default wordpress Recent Comment Widget?

Tags: wordpress

How to remove administrator's own comments on the default wordpress Recent Comment Widget? maybe with a function to exclude admin user id=1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a approach you can use, rather than modifying the default existing functionality why not copy the same to completely new custom widget of yours can then customize the copied code.

In wp-includes/default-widgets.php. 
You really should copy/create you own widget (just copy the part of the recent comments widget and customize the same to be functional and then modify it as per your requirements), then use that widget instead of the default into you blog.
 Get more help from [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) link.

Comment: My question is more like How to modify the widget, or maybe using any hooks function? anyone?